# NativeScript with Angular 2 custom html with Page tag

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm trying to create a custom page in NativeScript with Angular 2. I read somewhere that all I had to do was to add this into a html file.

```
<Page xmlns="http://www.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" loaded="pageLoaded" actionBarHidden="true">
<ActionBar title="Create">
    <NavigationButton text="Back" android.systemIcon="ic_menu_back"></NavigationButton>
    <ActionItem text="Save" (tap)="save()" ios.position="right"></ActionItem>
</ActionBar>
<StackLayout>
    <TextField hint="First Name" [(ngModel)]="firstname"></TextField>
    <TextField hint="Last Name" [(ngModel)]="lastname"></TextField>
</StackLayout>
</Page>
```

But this gives me an error. 
I also tried adding it to an xml file and updating the component template tag so it points to it instead.

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: "app",
    templateUrl: "pages/login/login.xml"
})
```

This gives errors too. 
So I'm confused. How do I add `Page` xml to the html file?

EDIT: I should of added that the reason I am adding `<Page>` is so I can hide the actionBar. I read that the only way I can do this is by adding `actionBarHidden="true"` to the `<Page>` element

Comment: I think you're missing some bootstrapping to this example. Isn't there a NativeScriptBootstrap module?

Comment: As @Knostradamus has pointed out, there could be implementation details that are missing. 

Aside from that, in my experience, I have not needed to wrap my page contents with the '<Page>' tag as you did above, have not needed the ".xml" extension -- ".html" works fine, and the file paths can be an issue. Be sure that your "templateUrl" is pointing to the correct place.

Comment: The reason I was trying to add "Page" was because I am trying to hide the actionBar and the only way I read to do it was to add actionBarHidden="true" to the "Page" tag. If there is another way, please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer to my main goal. 
Hiding the ActionBar can be done through dependency injection.

```
import {Page} from "ui/page";

@Component({
// ...
})
class MyComponent {
  constructor(page: Page) {
    page.actionBarHidden = true;
  }
}
```

https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-angular/issues/97